# Allocate more RAM to Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, speed

I have a lot of RAM on my computer, and recently allocated a bunch more to Firefox using this article: (http://smallbusiness.chron.com/set-ram-cache-firefox-41282.html)

I'd like to now do the same thing for Chrome, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Use the 64-bit version, by default, Chrome will use all the memory it needs.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Windows 64-bit. And, I'm asking this question because I want to change it, not because I want to use the default.

Answer (score 1):

Enter this into your chrome browser:

chrome://flags

Opens up a world of options.
Look for the "Maximum tiles" setting and you can up it to 512mb.

Comment: I have a lot more than 512mb, can I not make this number higher?